# Disable/Hide Header and Footer Howto

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I create my JQM app with multipage and external header footer. I initialize the header and footer with the following code at certain point of my app (not the first page of the app):

```
function initHeaderFooter(){
    $( "[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']" ).toolbar();
}
```

Now my problem, after user logout, back to first page, I'm having problem removing the header and footer.

I tried using the following code hope to have the header and footer remove. But instead of removing the bar, it show an Empty Bar instead of hiding the bar:

```
$('.ui-footer').html($('').navbar());
```

Please advice the proper way to remove header and footer.

**To show the header and footer again, I call the initialize function but it doesn't show up:**

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#userMainPage', function () {
    initHeaderFooter();
    $('.ui-footer').html($(
    '<div id="footerButton" data-role="navbar"><ul><li><a href="#restaurantList" data-transition="flow">Find Restaurant</a></li><li><a href="#">My Favourite</a></li></ul></div>'
).navbar()); });
```

Comment: You want to hide _navbar_ only or header/footer?

Comment: Hi @omar. Actually I need to hide both header and footer. Thanks.

Comment: But I'm testing it with the footer.

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/YdCXc/

Comment: Nice... toggleClass(). I'll read more and learn more about this. Thanks again @Omar. Do you want to create an Answer to I can mark it?

Comment: Great. I'll add an answer with explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide/show any element, you can simply add/remove `ui-screen-hidden` class. This class is simply a CSS class with `display: none;`. [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) is `.addClass()` + `.removeClass()` in one function.

Note that when you hide/show *toolbars*, you need to update page's height after showing/hiding them.

```
$("[data-role=header], [data-role=footer]")
    .toggleClass("ui-screen-hidden", function () {
    $.mobile.resetActivePageHeight();
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/YdCXc/)**

Comment: @Omar, to show it back after login, I tried the following code but the header and footer doesn't load. I added the code I use in my original post.

Comment: @user3053891 `$(".ui-footer")` to `$("[data-role=footer]")`.

Comment: @user3053891 to hide `.addClass("ui-screen-hidden")` to show  `.removeClass("ui-screen-hidden")`.

Comment: @Omar, just wanted to thank you again. I learn a lot and now I need to clear up my mind and restructure my code. Once again, thank you.

Comment: And I finally enough reputation to Vote Up... LOL.

Comment: @user3053891 you can chat too ;)